# cannot find symbol keyboard.nextInt

Tags: java, keyboard, symbols

```
int n;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
n = keyboard.nextInt();
```

My compiler is pointing to the dot in the statement n=keyboard.nextInt(); and providing a "cannot find symbol" error. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Did you import `java.util.Scanner`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

A minimal working example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n);
    }

}
```

Don't forget to import `java.util.scanner`.